# Site blocked by WebSense on fresh WP Install 

Tags: installation, theme-twenty-eleven, hacked

Just put up a new WP 3.2.1 install running twenty eleven, with one post "coming soon". I haven't yet begun developing the site. At my place of business, it is currently blocked by WebSense as "potentially damaging content", yet I was able to access the site yesterday.

Does it appear as if my site is hacked or has spam links, or does the web filter just not like my newfound sense of freedom? :)

The site is [here](http://www.traveling9to5.com/), I can't currently check into it due to the whole web filter issue. It does look fine on my iPhone, but I can't view source.

**Theme**: Twenty Eleven (no modifications)
**Plugins**: Remove Double Space

Comment: The site looks fine. Can't see any spam links or malicious code on home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websense blocks based on URLs, not on site content.

You can use their Site Lookup tool to have it fixed:
http://www.websense.com/sitelookup/

You'll have to register with their site.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like you are required to be a paid customer to use the site lookup tool. I checked over at webmasters and found [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/how-do-i-prevent-a-website-being-misclassified-by-websense) I guess my only option is to send an email to their 'suggest' alias.

Comment: I emailed, and they responded already indicating that they would re-categorize my site as "travel".